# ASP menu : how to avoid postback and access the selected value with a Javascript client side script

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms, postback

I have to implement a way to select values from an ASP horizontal menu (generated with a config file). The generation of the menu is not an issue: my actual problem is to find a way for the user to access its values without using postbacks.

I am working on a big and old project that was coded with the intent of not using PostBack requests at all. **Postback are by design unexpected and considered as bugs**.

In order to reach my goal, I tried to code a JavaScript trigger for the MenuItemClick event that ends with return false, in order to avoid postbacks (currently the JavaScript code is limited to a simple test alert and the false return, for testing purposes). But this doesn't work: I can't get the event to fire the JavaScript function: a post back happens, which is undesired.

The complete code consist of thousands lines (most of them unrelated to the issue), here is an abridged version with only the relevant lines:

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CRB" Namespace="ConfigurableReportBuilder.PageControls" Assembly="ConfigurableReportBuilder" %>
<form id="form1" class="page" runat="server">    
    <CRB:HorizontalMenu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" RootNode="Menu/Items" StyleClass="ui-menu ui-state-hover"/>
    //this works fine, no issue here.
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
(...)
if (this.IsPostBack)
    throw new Exception("PostBack requests are not expected to occur");
    //Ensure that "PostBack requests" (which are unexpected and therefore indicate bugs) become recognized by a specific exception which is thrown here
```

Workspace.js:

```
var WS = (function ($) {
    var test = function (event) {
        alert("test"); 
        return false; //prevent postback
    };
    (...)
    return {// This dictionary contains references to public methods used in the project
        test: test,
        (...)
    }
}

$(document).on("menuitemclick", '#MainMenu', WS.test); //setting the event trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that does achieve the desired goal, but beware, **it doesn't respect good practices of coding**. There might be better solutions available, but i can't find any.

The idea is to abandon the MenuItemClick event based logic and revert to the default behavior of an ASP menus, having URLs as clickable menu items(NavigateUrl). The URLs will are accessible in the main page without any postback, they can therefore be used to carry the information... as small JavaScript codes.

In order to do this, one must set raw Javascript code as NavigateUrl parameters during the initialization of the menu items:

```
protected MenuItem getMenuItem(XmlNode menuNode)
{//function that initialize a MenuItem with an XML node as parameter

    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem(); //creating a MenuItem object

    //Assigning its properties: 
    mi.Text = menuNode.Attributes["text"].Value; 
    if (menuNode.Attributes["description"] != null)
        mi.ToolTip = menuNode.Attributes["description"].Value;
    if (menuNode.Attributes["configfile"] != null) {
        mi.Value = menuNode.Attributes["configfile"].Value;
        mi.NavigateUrl = "javascript:alert('"+mi.Value+"');"; //Note that this isn't an URL
    }
}
```

The URL from the ASP menu are therefore not links but functions that will be executed by in the main page, without going though any event. Theses function can therefore be used to retrieve the desired values, without going though any postbacks-events : in the example I just gave, an alert window displays the selected dropdown value.